# JS CustomElements - Self 'registration' upon first instantiation

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

so I was looking for a way to setup an ES6 'abstract' base class for custom elements, which self-registers (window.customElements.define) upon the first instantiation of a child.

The approach I came up with is the following:

```js
class MyBase extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(tag, child) {
    MyBase.register(tag, child);
    super();
    
    if(this.constructor.name === MyBase) {
      throw new Error('Error: Do not instantiate base class!');
    }
  }
  
  static register(tag, child) {
    if(!window.customElements.get(tag)) {
      window.customElements.define(tag, child);
    }
  }
}

class MyChild extends MyBase {
  constructor() {
    super(MyChild.Tag(), MyChild);
    
    if(window.customElements.get(MyChild.Tag())) {
      console.log(`${this.constructor.name} registered!`)
    }
  }
  static Tag() {
    return "my-child";
  }
}

const NiceChild = new MyChild();
```

Is there a way to avoid the statics and the MyBase constructor parameters? I've tried various approaches but I wasn't able to figure out a more elegant solution due to the fact that the registration must be called before the HTMLElement constructor is called. Also, I of course don't want the registration to be performed if MyBase is instantiated directly.

**Edit:**

I've added another snippet to showcase that the registration in fact happens upon instantiation of MyChild.

```js
class MyBase extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(tag, child) {
    MyBase.register(tag, child);
    super();
    
    if(this.constructor.name === MyBase) {
      throw new Error('Error: Do not instantiate base class!');
    }
  }
  
  static register(tag, child) {
    if(!window.customElements.get(tag)) {
      window.customElements.define(tag, child);
    }
  }
}

class MyChild extends MyBase {
  constructor() {
    super(MyChild.Tag(), MyChild);
  }
  static Tag() {
    return "my-child";
  }
}

if(window.customElements.get("my-child")) {
  console.log(`Before Constructor: my-child registered!`)
} else {
  console.log(`Before Constructor: my-child not registered!`)
}

const NiceChild = new MyChild();

if(window.customElements.get("my-child")) {
   console.log(`After Constructor: my-child registered!`)
} else {
   console.log(`After Constructor: my-child not registered!`)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is not where you register your custom element: you register it "immediately" with your class declaration, and then if you want your code to start running only after the browser has finished loading that in, wait for it.

And note that, because we can call `customElements.define` statically inside a class, we can also register subclasses by calling the base class's `register` using a static assignment (but then you'll want to mark it as a private field because it'll be "useless" to anything else)

```css
other-thing {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<other-thing>from html source</other-thing>

<!-- note that this is ESM -->
<script type="module">
  /**
   * JS has no "abstract" classes. This is just a normal base class,
   * and it won't be something folks can use because we're not
   * going to register it as a usable custom element.
   */
  class Thing extends HTMLElement {
    static register(tag, child) {
      if(!customElements.get(tag)) {
        customElements.define(tag, child);
      } else {
        console.warn(`<${tag}> already exists, skipping registration`);
      }
    }
    // This class's constructor should basically "do nothing".
    // For custom elements, the function that matters is connectCallback()
  }

  /**
   * This class _will_ be usable, because we're going to register
   * it with its own custom tag "<other-thing>".
   */
  class OtherThing extends Thing {
    // Immediately Register this class's custom tag:
    static #register = Thing.register(`other-thing`, this);

    // And whenever instances are added to the DOM, do something:
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log(`text content = ${this.textContent}`);
    }
  }

  // Then wait for the browser to finish with that:
  await customElements.whenDefined(`other-thing`);

  // And then we can do whatever we want.
  const myOtherThing = new OtherThing();
  myOtherThing.textContent = `from the JS side`;
  document.body.appendChild(myOtherThing);
</script>
```

Also note that you don't want to do all that much of *anything* in your constructor: not only do you not want to register the custom element until an instance is created, when the constructor runs there isn't even a DOM node to work with yet. That only happens when the element gets inserted into the DOM, at which point [the connectedCallback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#custom_element_lifecycle_callbacks) gets called.

Comment: Well this is - apart from the waiting - the thing I currently do within the solution above. I just want the registration `(customElements.define(\`other-thing\`, OtherThing))` to be scoped.

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post for further detail about what exactly happens. I want the registration scoped within my base class to ensure every child which inherits from that base class is registered upon instantiation.

Comment: Also: no, it's very much not what you currently do given the code in your post: the code you're showing runs a class registration only once an instance is constructed _using a `new` call on the JS side_, which means that any `<your-tag>` content in your page's HTML source will _not_ get upgraded until that happens.

Comment: I know that it happens. I am looking for a more elegant approach to achieve exactly this. My complete markup will be generated by js. I don't use static html pages.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I see, yeah that now makes sense to me!

Comment: I've updated the code to show the static register call. Also removed my comments that are now no longer necessary.